# What is the meaning of the 'secret' keyword in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I can see in defaults/main.yml for specific role: `ftp_user: secret`.
Search through Google for any hints brings me to the vault related articles. There is no `vault_password_file` option is in the ansible.cfg nor vault related files found on the file system.

Please explain the meaning of 'secret' keyword found on place of variable value in the Ansible files? Where stored the values that gonna be substituted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ftp_user: secret`

There is no keyword in this piece of [yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/):

- `ftp_user` is a key
- `secret` is the value for that key, a scalar, literally the string `secret`

Since this is in your role's `defaults/main.yml`, it means that it will be your default value for the `ftp_user` variable in your role unless you override it in your inventory/playbook.